# Excluding META-INF signed jar entries from combined single ueber jar

Tags: scala, sbt

It is standard practice to use `MergeStrategy.discard` to remove signed jar entries present in jar files from a combined / single / ueber-jar. Here is the snippet from `build.sbt`:  in particular pay attention to the second and third entries that refer to the `DSA` :

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
  case n if n.startsWith("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.toUpperCase.startsWith("META-INF/.*.DSA") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.toUpperCase.startsWith("META-INF/*.DSA") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.toUpperCase.startsWith("META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case n if n.toUpperCase.startsWith("META-INF/ECLIPSEF.SF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x if x.contains("apache") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x if x.contains("log") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x if x.contains("google") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x if x.contains("journal") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x if x.contains("slf4j") => MergeStrategy.first
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
}
```

But the generated assembly jar does contain some DSA entries:

```
18:51:20/tmsjobs $jar -tvf memsql/target/scala-2.10/memsql-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | egrep "DUMMY|DSA"
  1042 Fri Jan 30 22:08:48 PST 2015 META-INF/DUMMY.DSA
 36829 Fri Jan 30 22:08:48 PST 2015 META-INF/DUMMY.SF
```

What is missing/incorrect in the exclusion / discard strategy?  (And secondarily which of the lines 2 or 3 are the correct format i.e. `.*.DSA` or `*.DSA` . Thanks.

Comment: could you share you build.sbt?

Comment: Not sure this will solve your issue, but `<<=` is deprecated. Last time I used `sbt-assembly` I used the `:=` operator (example here: https://github.com/stefanobaghino/spark-twitter-stream-example/blob/96681c259022031303950ced1be2b1c6ef018a63/build.sbt)

Comment: @mysterion  I can not share the rest of the `build.sbt`.  afaik the mergeStrategy would be the only area affecting this .. ( are there others potentially)?  thx

Comment: let's say i am more curious with this particular dependency that causing troubles